# Xcode: Getting the path for AppleScript file in Obj-C/Cocoa project with pathpathForResource

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, path, applescript

I have a plugin development project in X-code (10.2.1), and am trying to incorporate some AppleScript code (FatApple.applescript) into one of the methods in my implementation file.

On the AppleScript side: I have tried writing the code in Script Editor, saving to Desktop, dragging and dropping the FatApple.scptd in the "Resources", "Other Sources", etc. folders. I have tried the same steps after starting a new Xcode Project for AppleScript and dragging and dropping the FatApple.applescript file (tried with pathWithFormat type as both "scpt" and "applescript".

In Xcode I have added the FatApple.applescript to the Copy Bundle Resources, and removed from Compile Resources.

```
-(float) calcThing
{
    NSAlert *alert=[[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"FatApple" ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSString *countstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"path=%@",path];
        [alert setMessageText: countstr];
        [alert runModal];
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error:nil];
        [script executeAndReturnError:nil];
}
```

I would expect to compile and run my plugin, call it in the program and receive a message with the path to my AppleScript, then ideally I could call the script and start doing stuff. Instead I receive "path=(null)".

Comment: Getting the path of a regular file works for me - note that `.scptd` would be a script _bundle_ (a folder).  Are your files actually getting copied to the application bundle?

Comment: When I drag and drop the .applescript I'm selecting "Copy items if needed", "Create groups", and "add to targets" for my plugin. If I am putting the applescript in an Xcode project, do I need to bring anything over to my plugin other than the .applescript? (i.e., framework/plist/etc.)

Comment: Additional frameworks aren't needed for an AppleScript.  You may be setting build phases, but is the script actually making it into the application bundle, in the resource folder you are targeting?

Comment: After compiling, I'm seeing FatApple.applescript in my pkugin as Plugin/Contents/Resources/FatApple.scpt

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code verbatim into a project and it worked for me, using a dummy AppleScript. The only difference I can see is that I dropped the AppleScript in the main file list rather than in the resources folder, but that shouldn't make any difference. The script shows up in the app resources folder like yours does.

The only questionable thing I see in your code is that you used NSBundle's `- pathForResource:ofType:` instead of `- URLForResource:withExtension:`. NSAppleScript wants an NSURL, so asking the bundle for a *path* and then converting it to a URL seems like an unnecessary step, and unnecessary steps are inherently suspicious. I can't see why that would make a difference (unless the plugin context does something funky to resource file paths), but, you know...